# Centering bootstrap panel with rows vertically and horizontally

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to center a bootstrap panel vertically and horizontally. The
structure of the document is as follows:

```
<body>
  <div class="container parent">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body text-center">A Basic Panel</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The CSS:

```
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/69253/)

This seems to center the panel horizontally, but not vertically. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did two changes :

Html

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
```

Css(should be declared after bootstrap css stylesheet):

```
.panel{
    margin-top: -25px;
}
.parent {
    height: 100vh;
    padding-top: 50vh;
}
```

Why margin-top: `-25px` ? because in the developers console i saw that `.panel` css box model is taking `50px` in height and its starting from `50 vh` height(so it will not be centered and will go below extra `25px`) so i subtracted the extra height from .panel to center it correctly.

Comment: You should stick away from using `!important`. This can lead to problematic code for people who didn't put it there themselves, or a future you if you forget about putting it there.

Answer (score 1):

You can't center a col-md-3 because there are 12 columns total, leaving 9 behind, which you cant split evenly. If you had an even number of columns you were using, you could use col-md-offset-#.

Comment: Good point -- but it looks like after doing so, the panel doesn't center vertically. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, if you want more control over the positioning of your elements, try using flexbox. https://flexbox.io/

Comment: Also keep in mind that you can nest bootstrap columns. In theory, you could nest 12 columns in 12 columns in 12 columns, and just by setting divs to plain color you could create pixel art.

Answer (score 1):

You can center something vertically by using `.parent { top: 50% }`

The `%` value can be changed depending where you would like it to appear.

This value is also determined by the percentage of the `div` size that your element is inside.